# How do you limit the number of API requests in Express.js

Tags: javascript, express, express-rate-limit

I have a website that I am building. In this website, I am adding Q&A type forums to certain parts of it. I want to allow the users to be able to vote up or down on answers, but limit them to only vote up or down once (but be able to remove/change their vote).

I am using Ajax on the frontend to send the request to the backend. I could add some code to limit it on the frontend, but because frontend code is available to the client, they could easily change that code, so I need to have code in the backend to handle this.

I looked up a bunch of things, and almost all of them were saying to use `express-rate-limit` library, and do something like this:

```js
const rateLimit = require('express-rate-limit');

const limiter = rateLimit({
    windowMs: 2000,
    max: 1
});

router.post('/route', limiter, ...);
```

This still doesn't quite work. Sometimes if I click a bunch really fast all those requests are sent, and then something goes wrong and messes up the vote count.

I don't know what to try next. Does anyone know how to fix this?

The following is my backend code to handle the requests:

```js
exports.postVote = (req, res, next) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req)
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) return res.status(400).json(errors.array()[0].msg)
    return Message
        .findById(req.body.messageId)
        .then((message) => {
            if (message.userId.toString() == req.user._id.toString())
                return res.status(400).json('You cannot vote on your own post!')
            else {
                return Vote
                    .findOne({ userId: req.user._id.toString(), messageId: message._id.toString() })
                    .then((vote) => {
                        if (vote) {
                            if (vote.direction == req.body.direction) {
                                if (vote.direction == 'up') message.votes--
                                else if (vote.direction == 'down') message.votes++
                                else return res.status(500).json('Something didn\'t work out, please try again')

                                message.save()
                                vote.remove()
                                return res.json({ message: 'removed', votes: message.votes })
                            }
                            else {
                                if (req.body.direction == 'up') message.votes+=2
                                else if (req.body.direction == 'down') message.votes-=2
                                message.save()
                                vote.direction = (vote.direction == 'up' ? 'down' : 'up')
                                vote.save()
                                return res.json({ message: 'changed', votes: message.votes })
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            let messageVote = new Vote({
                                messageId: message._id,
                                userId: req.user._id,
                                direction: req.body.direction
                            })
                            if (req.body.direction == 'down') message.votes--
                            else if (req.body.direction == 'up') message.votes++
                            else return res.status(500).json('Something didn\'t work out, please try again')

                            message.save()
                            messageVote.save()
                            return res.json({ message: 'added', votes: message.votes })
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(e => {
                        console.log(e)
                        return res.status(500).json('Something didn\'t work out, please try again')
                    })
            }
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(e)
            return res.status(500).json('Something didn\'t work out, please try again')
        })
}
```

---

A few of the articles/tutorials I found talked about how the limit only starts once the number of requests goes over the `max`, is this true? Or does that `limiter` say that there can only be 1 request every 2 seconds? If it is true, should I say `max: 0` (so that it will immediately start limiting the requests)?

---

Does `express-rate-limit` actually limit the requests? Or does it just delay requests?
If it limits it, with me limiting it to 1 request every 2 seconds, why does it still mess up?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Only voting up or down once has nothing to do with rate limiting.  To implement a vote once policy, you will need to have a back-end data store where you keep track of what answers a given user has voted on so you can tell if they've already voted or not on any given question.  You can store that by user (every question/answer they've voted on) or you can store it by question (every user that has voted on it).  Either way can work.  Then, when you get a new incoming vote, you can check the back-end data store to see if the user has already made a vote on this question or not.

Comment: That is how I do it. But with sending so many requests, I don't think everything is updated when each request tries to do what it's supposed to, and so it can't tell if they have voted up yet or if they are trying to remove their up-vote, and so things get messed up.

Comment: That sounds like back-end race conditions.  You have to fix the way you update your back-end store so that multiple requests don't interfere with each other.  This is typically done by doing atomic updates or short term locks.  You don't show any of your back-end code so we have no idea what you are or aren't doing there.

Comment: I _did_ think that it might be the way that I handle it, but I couldn't think of anything that I do that would mess it up (or allow it to be messed up). I updated my question to include the backend function I wrote.

Comment: Lots of non-atomic operations here.  You have a `.find()` or a `.findOne()` and then some other logic and then based on what you found, you update the database.  This is a classic race condition because another request can be in the middle of doing the exact same thing and thus they are both trying to update the same data, but neither has the right data to make decisions on because they're both updating at the same time.  I'd suggest doing some reading on "atomic" operations in your database.  That's where the database, finds and updates something for you in one fell swoop.

Comment: Is that even possible with MongoDB? I looked up "atomic operation with MongoDB" and the first few things were saying that there were no atomic operations for multiple documents, and since I need to update both a `Vote` and a `Message` document, I really have no idea what to do, or if it can be done...

Comment: It should be possible.  The race condition is in the Vote document, not the Message document where you are deciding if this user can do this vote and/or what to do based on the direction.  If you eliminate the race conditions in the Vote document, you can easily update the Message document without race conditions.  The classic race condition is 1) Get object from database, 2) Use some logic based on what you found to update the object, 3) Write changed object back to the database.  Any other code doing the same thing at the same time will conflict leading to possible race conditions.

Comment: @JacobHornbeck create unique index for both userId and messageId. So you can ensure only one vote can be there for a message.

Comment: @Pranavan MongoDB automatically creates an id for new documents created. I use those ids to update the values instead of creating new ones. The duplicates aren't the problem, as jfriend00 is saying, it's the race conditions that are causing the problems.

Comment: @jfriend00, I don't think using an atomic operation will work. I looked it up and am trying to implement it, but with the different conditions I check for and change based on, I can't change how I need it to.

Comment: Then, you should consider changing how you store data in the database so that you can use atomic operations to do your updates.  This is a holistic design problem.  The design of how/what you store needs to match what you're trying to do and what atomic operations you need to do.  I don't understand your data design well enough to make a more specific recommendation - but the problem is solvable with the right data design and proper coding of database updates.

Comment: @jfriend00 I need to add a new document if there isn't one created yet, and I don't see any atomic operation that will allow me to update it if it exist, or create it if it doesn't.

Comment: The limiter thing that I have right now, seems to be working now, even though I didn't change anything, which doesn't make any sense....

Comment: `findOneAndUpdate()` with the `upsert` option is how you update or insert atomically.  There are other ways to do it with unique indexes.  I'm not a mongodb export at all so others could help you with specifics better than I.

Comment: For more complicated situations, you can lock individual documents and there are multiple concurrency control options, but your error handling has to be perfect so you can't ever leave a lock on.  I mention this because the code you show is missing a bunch of error handling.